# How to Serialize Hashtable with ServiceStack JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, hashtable, servicestack

I'm trying to serialize a `Hashtable` with ServiceStack `JsonSerializer`. Unlike Json.Net and built-in `JavaScriptSerializer`, however, it returns type names of `DictionaryEntry` instead of values.

This code:

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable(){ { "A", 1 }, { "B", 2 } };

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(h));
Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(h));
Console.WriteLine(ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(h, typeof(Hashtable)));
```

Returns this:

```
{"A":1,"B":2}
{"A":1,"B":2}
["System.Collections.DictionaryEntry","System.Collections.DictionaryEntry"]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: a) Don't use ServiceStack's JsonSerializer or b) Don't use Hashtable

Comment: @L.B, that's not very constructive, and I find it condescending. The question was "How to ...", not "What should I do?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of [ServiceStack.Text](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) (v3.9.11+) on NuGet now includes support for Hashtable.